# Issue with running commands from shell script

Tags: unix, copy, sftp, remote-access

I'm trying to copy files from a remote windows server to Unix server. I was successfully able to copy files from windows server using command prompt but when I run these commands from a script it's not working as expected.

commands used:

`sftp user@remoteserver.com`

`lcd local_dir`

`cd remote dir`

`get file_name`

`exit`

When I run these commands from a script the script is stopping after it connects to the remote server.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: You are making things more complicated that you have to: use `scp` instead of `sftp` for such purposes if the server offers it, it is much easier to use in scripts since you can execute a single command instead of having to interact. If you are stuck with `sftp` try not to use it in an interactive manner, but inside some wrapper like `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Tried scp earlier it's not working so moved to this. Can you elaborate ur answer if possible

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Certainly scp does work. I use it daily. It is as simple as `scp user@remoteserver.com/remote_dir/filename local_dir/`

Comment: getting `exec request failed on channel 0 lost connection`.

Comment: Sorry, I posted a syntax error before, my fault. It must be: `scp user@remoteserver.com:/remote_dir/filename local_dir/` (note the additional colon (`:`)). If that does not work then try directly from a command like first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands `lcd` to `exit` are `sftp` commands, so you cannont just write them into a script line by line but have to redirect them as `sftp`s stdin:

```
 # all lines till "EOF" will be redirected to sftp
 sftp user@remoteserver.com <<- EOF
 lcd local_dir
 cd remote dir
 get file_name
 exit
 EOF

 # here you are in your shell script again, eg:
 SFTPRES=$?
```